# Oracle Apex: How to both hide or show a region when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a button and a region.
When the button is pressed, I want it to show the region if the region is hidden, and hide the region if the region is shown. I'm trying to do this with a JavaScript condition. Here are the button and the region in the rendering pane:

[image: Rendering pane]

Under the button there's a Dynamic Action that's triggered when the button is pressed. If the result is True then it should show the region and if the result is false then it should hide the region.

So all that is left is to add a JavaScript Expression under Client-side Condition to this Dynamic Action, something like

```
if (*region is visible*)
    return false;//hide the region
else
    return true;//show the region
```

Problem is I don't know what the code is to find if a region is visible. I assigned a Static ID to the region called `TestRegionID`, and I guess it is referenced in JavaScript like this: `$(TestRegionID)`

So how do I write this JavaScript expression?

**Update:** Answer is just put `($(TestRegionID).is(":visible"))` in the JavaScript expression box and flip the Hide and Show action positions (True -> Hide, False -> Show)

Answer (score 1):

There are other approaches than what you're trying. Here is an example of how to do it with a single region/button. Instead of using a single button, I'm using 2 buttons (a hide button and a show button) and hiding/showing only the relevant one. Set the initial state with an on page load dynamic action and from then on, code the dynamic actions so there can not be any confusion.

For the example I have the following components:

- Region R1
- Button "Show R1"
- Button "Hide R1"

When the page is launched, only the "Show R1" button should be visible and the region and "Hide R1" button should be hidden, so there is a dynamic action (da) on page load:

- name: "Set initial state"

  - true action: Hide

    - affected elements: Region R1
  - true action: Hide

    - affected elements: Button Hide R1

Test this. Only the button "Show R1" should be visible on page load.

Now create a dynamic action on click of button Show R1:

- name: "Show Region R1"

  - true action: Hide

    - affected elements: Button Show R1
  - true action: Show

    - affected elements: Button Hide R1
  - true action: Show

    - affected elements: Region R1

This dynamic action will show the region, hide the "show" button and show the "hide" button. Now all that is left to do is to create the "opposite" da, to be used when the "hide" button is visible:

- name: "Hide Region R1"

  - true action: Hide

    - affected elements: Button Hide R1
  - true action: Show

    - affected elements: Button Show R1
  - true action: Hide

    - affected elements: Region R1

This is it. If you add more buttons you'll need a "show" and a "hide" dynamic action for each of the buttons to toggle show/hide for all the buttons and regions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but this seems like a convoluted way of doing it. Is it possible to just know whether a region is hidden or not?

Comment: Yeah it's a lot of dynamic actions, on the other hand, it's very clear how it works and you only need to do it once

Comment: You could add a class to the button to indicate the region is shown, but then the user experience isn't optimal and how should it work if there are 2 regions ? If region 1 is open and user clicks region 2 button - should it hide region 1 and toggle that button ? Whichever way you go it's a lot of logic that need to be programmed when a user clicks a button

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to check if a region has been hidden with a standard Hide.

```
$('#my-region').css('display')
```

This can be your JavaScript expression, and have show/hide true/false conditions.

I often do a similar thing by [checking if any rows returned](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2018/09/orcle-apex-hide-region-if-no-data-found.html) in my region.

```
$(this.triggeringElement).find('.nodatafound').length == 1
```

Comment: I used this `($(TestRegionID).is(":visible"))` it's the only thing that worked